# SQL - Using CTE and effectively select rows at a specific row_number()

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, where-clause, row-number

In this scenario is the SELECT TOP necessary within the CTE (micro optimization, I know...).

```
DECLARE @pageSize INT, @currentPage INT, @top INT
SET @pageSize = 10
SET @currentPage = 150
SET @top = @pageSize * @currentPage + @pageSize

WITH t AS
(
    SELECT TOP(***@top***) ID, name
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS _row,
    FROM dbo.User
)
SELECT TOP(@pageSize) *
FROM t
WHERE t._row > (@top-@pageSize)
ORDER BY t.ID
```

The above returns 10 (@pageSize) rows from a start number (@top-@pageSize) in a specific order with a row number column.
Does the CTE statement know that the "SELECT TOP" outside of the CTE and the WHERE-clause, also outside the CTE, is to come, hence the CTE never returns more rows in the specific order than needed?

Basically just talking about the ROW_NUMBER function, that it does not count a row number for rows not returned (if I were to have millions of rows...), and also if I were to select top 100 in the CTE, would row_number still be calculated for all the million rows within the table selected?

I have tried with and without "SELECT TOP(@top)" in the CTE-statement, inside a loop with 10.000 runs, without seeing any difference in time usage. Though, I have only 38.000 rows in the table at the moment.

Edit:
So the result:

```
    WITH t AS
(
    **DO A TOP() WITH AN ORDER BY IN THE CTE**
    SELECT TOP(@top) ID, name 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS _row,
    FROM dbo.User
    ORDER BY ID
)
SELECT TOP(@pageSize) * 
**SELECTING TOP N FROM THE CTE, WHERE ROW-NUMBER IS ... DUE TO THE CTE IS IN ORDER ALREADY**
FROM t
WHERE t._row > (@top-@pageSize)
```

This could probably be more efficient if I ORDERED them "backwards", selecting the "bottom @pageSize" of the CTE, which would leave out the where-clause...  but that would require some test if it actually were faster...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of `top` without an `order by` is discouraged.  There is no guarantee that you will get the rows that you want, so you should not include the `top`.  Or, you should include an `order by id`, if that is the ordering that you want.

The user of `top` doesn't affect the `row_number()` calculation, because that calculation is going to be done before the `top` is applied.  You can imagine having another window function there, such as `sum() over ()` to understand that the `top` cannot generally be applied before the `row_number()` and finding the circumstances where it is safe would be hard work.

Comment: Of course, it requires an order by within the CTE to use the top, else you would get the order of which the rows are stored and based on those you return 10 based on an order by... So, thanks for pointing that out. But, if the table had 100 million rows, how to optimize the CTE? To me, as I read the CTE, it selects ID, name and calculates a row number for every row within the table, 100 million rows, this would be a tad slow, even if the "last part" of the query just selects rows from 15.000 to 15.010...???

Comment: @ØyvindBerg . . . You *do not* get the order in which the rows are stored when you leave out an `order by`.  You get an arbitrary ordering, which might often be related to access methods, but there are no, no, no guarantees.

Comment: I did not mean first INSERTED row is always the first SELECTED when leaving out the "order by"... But in the order they are "stored" where the store order ("arbitrary" order) is defined by criterias such as indexes, etc... But I think I got this, edited my question and marked your reply as answer. "Since row_number() is done before top"...

Answer (score 1):

If you have a supporting index on `ID` you do not have to read and enumerate the whole table. SQL Server will have to read the table up to and including the page you want. So if for example you want page 1 (rows 11 to 20) the query will only fetch 20 rows. And that is true even if you don't use the top in the CTE.

A table to test on with some data:

```
create table dbo.[User]
(
  ID int identity primary key,
  Name nvarchar(128)
)

go

insert into dbo.[User](Name)
select top(1000) Name
from sys.all_objects
```

A query without the redundant top expressions.

```
DECLARE @pageSize INT, @currentPage INT, @top INT;
SET @pageSize = 10;
SET @currentPage = 1;
SET @top = @pageSize * @currentPage + @pageSize;
with C as
(
  select U.ID,
         U.Name,
         row_number() over(order by U.ID) as rn
  from dbo.[User] as U
)
select C.ID,
       C.Name
from C
where C.rn > @pageSize * @currentPage and 
      C.rn <= @pageSize * (@currentPage + 1);
```

This will give you a query plan like this:

[image]

The number by each operator is the number of rows actually fetched. The clustered index scan reads 20 rows ordered by `ID`. Segment and Sequence Project enumerates the rows. Top is the operator that makes sure that no more than 20 rows is fetched. The filter removes the rows 1 to 10 and let the rows 11 to 20 through.

If we instead try to get page 5 (`@currentPage = 5` to get rows 51 to 60) the plan will look like this:

[image]

Top operator makes sure only 60 rows is read from the clustered index and the filter filters out the first 50 rows to return the last 10 rows.

Using your last query with the extra top expressions will not add anything of value. Only one extra redundant top operator.

[image]

The key to understand what is going on in the query plan is to know that execution is done from left to right demanding one row at a time. That is how the top operator can stop the clustered index scan when enough rows are returned.

Comment: Numbers equals amount of rows fetched, nice (never noticed those before). So; the top in the CTE in this scenario is not required, it gives actually an overhead, because SQL already optimizes the query by "thinking ahead" based on the where-clause in the "main query" then. This was my assumption all along, so that's fine. I'll try it out myself to see what happens for the various columns I need the CTE for. Ehm one more thing, when you add the "redundant top", Clustered index uses 98.2% time, filter only 1.2 for "cost of" +0.1 top and +0.1% top again, and 0.1% segment...Or SQL was "warm"? :P

Comment: The cost is an **estimate** done before the query is executed using statistics and heuristics. The cost is the estimate even in an actual execution plan. The query optimizer is cost based and those numbers are what was used to compare different execution plans. It has nothing to do with how a query actually executed.

Comment: "Has nothing to do with how it actually executes"... But the estimation was "better" with a TOP... So I am not 100% convinced... But I trust you. :)

Comment: @ØyvindBerg Have a look at [Execution Plan Basics](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/execution-plan-basics/) the section **The Query Optimizer** talks about how cost works.